# When to use Wordpress loop or Foreach loop?

Tags: query-posts, loop, customization

Under what circumstances would you, (should you?) use a foreach loop, instead of the wordpress loop.

I have no real coding need, but I'm curious. What's good practice here?

Should I:

```
    $args=array(
    'post_parent' => $pos_id,
  );

$sublabels=get_posts($args);
  foreach($sublabels as $sublabel) { // blabla something to do foreach}
```

Or:

```
    query_posts(array(
    'post_parent' => $pos_id,
'cat' => 'label',

    ));

 while (have_posts()) : the_post() ?> // and then the blabla something for each
```

And why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your examples are showing two different thing The first one is looping over categories and the second is looping over posts, so the answer in this case is simple and depends on what you need to loop over (posts or categories).

No if you meant when should you use [**`query_posts()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) vs. [**`get_posts()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) vs. [**`WP_Query`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query)
then take a look at this [**`awesome answer`**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/2487) .

Comment: Ahhhaa. I was going to edit it and ask again, but actually it is essentially a question of 'get_posts' vs query_posts. Ha. Oops. Sorry for the reask then :) And thanks for the swift answer and link!